# C# Pivot table data into a ViewModel using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, entity-framework-core

I have a use case that contains data stored in a values tables as shown below, that needs to be pivot based on a JobLevel and displayed in a DataGridControl, however in order to get this working I firstly need to transform the data table I receive from the database into a ViewModel object that can display the result as a row, to allow users can be able to modify the values column on the DataGridControl. The table stores  information pertaining to employees in various levels and a count of employees in each level and what their color and gender are. If a value has no data, it should default to zero.

Job Level enum:

```cs
public enum JobLevel
{
    Top,
    Mid,
    Low
}

public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}

public enum Gender
{
    Female,
    Male,
    Other
}
```

Values entity class:

```cs
public class EmployeeGroupValue
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    public JobLevel JobLevel { get;set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    public Gender Gender { get;set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    public Color Color { get;set; }
    [Required]
    public int Value { get;set; }
}
```

Example of 'Values' data:

| Id | JobLevel | Gender | Color | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Top | Male | Red | 10 |
| 2 | Top | Other | Red | 5 |
| 3 | Top | Female | Blue | 20 |
| 4 | Mid | Other | Blue | 5 |
| 5 | Mid | Female | Green | 50 |
| 6 | Low | Male | Green | 5 |
| 7 | Low | Other | Red | 7 |
| 8 | Low | Female | Green | 12 |

Employee Group Values DataGrid View:

| JobLevel | Female | Male | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| xxxxxxxxxxxx | R | B | G | R | B | G | R | B | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Top | 0 | 20 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| Mid | 0 | 0 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Low | 0 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 7 | 0 | 0 |

Suggested View Model:

```cs
public class EmployeeGroupValueViewModel
{
     public string JobLevel { get;set; }
     public int FemaleRed { get;set; }
     public int FemaleBlue { get;set; }
     public int FemaleGreen { get;set; }
     public int MaleRed { get;set; }
     public int MaleBlue { get;set; }
     public int MaleGreen { get;set; }
     public int OtherRed { get;set; }
     public int OtherBlue { get;set; }
     public int OtherGreen { get;set; }
}
```

How can I transform my data using linq into such a view model and default Value to zero where there are no rows in the database?

Comment: You show no duplicates of Gender or Color for a particular JobLevel - is it possible for there to be duplicates at the lower levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom enhanced `Dictionary` that returns `default(TValue)` for missing entries, you can remap the source data to a tree of dictionaries and avoid re-scanning the data for each property value.

Here is the enhanced `Dictionary` and some extension methods to make using it easier with LINQ:

```
#region Enhanced Dictionaries
public static class DictExt {
    // DefaultDictionary that returns default(TValue) for missing entries
    public static DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDefaultDictionary<T, TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> keyFn, Func<T, TValue> valFn) {
        var nd = new DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            nd.Add(keyFn(item), valFn(item));
        return nd;
    }
    public static DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> items, Func<TValue, TKey> keyFn) {
        var nd = new DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            nd.Add(keyFn(item), item);
        return nd;
    }
    public static DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> srcd)
        => new DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>(srcd);
 }

//***
// Enhanced Dictionary that returns default(TValue) for missing entries
//***
public class DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    public DefaultDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> d) : base() {
        foreach (var kvp in d)
            Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
    public DefaultDictionary() : base() { }

    public new TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            TryGetValue(key, out var val);
            return val;
        }
        set => base[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you can use it with LINQ to convert the original sparse data into dictionaries. I assumed the data might contain duplicate values at any level.

```
var jobLevelDict = 
    values
        .GroupBy(v => v.JobLevel)
        .ToDefaultDictionary(
            vg => vg.Key,
            vjlg => vjlg
                    .GroupBy(v => v.Gender)
                    .ToDefaultDictionary(
                        vgg => vgg.Key,
                        vgg => vgg
                                .GroupBy(v => v.Color)
                                .ToDefaultDictionary(
                                    vcg => vcg.Key,
                                    vcg => vcg.Sum(v => v.Value))));
```

One you have the tree of dictionaries, you can build the full `List<EmployeeGroupValueViewModel>` for the grid:

```
var ans = Enum.GetValues<JobLevel>()
             .Select(jl => new EmployeeGroupValueViewModel {
                     JobLevel = jl.ToString(),
                     FemaleRed = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Female]?[Color.Red] ?? 0,
                     FemaleBlue = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Female]?[Color.Blue] ?? 0,
                     FemaleGreen = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Female]?[Color.Green] ?? 0,
                     MaleRed = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Male]?[Color.Red] ?? 0,
                     MaleBlue = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Male]?[Color.Blue] ?? 0,
                     MaleGreen = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Male]?[Color.Green] ?? 0,
                     OtherRed = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Other]?[Color.Red] ?? 0,
                     OtherBlue = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Other]?[Color.Blue] ?? 0,
                     OtherGreen = jobLevelDict?[jl]?[Gender.Other]?[Color.Green] ?? 0
                 })
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```cs
var databaseData = context.EmployeeGroupValues
    .GroupBy(e => new { e.JobLevel, e.Gender, e.Color })
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        g.Key.JobLevel,
        g.Key.Gender,
        g.Key.Color,
        Value = g.Sum(x => x.Value)
    })
    .ToList();

var enrichedData = 
    from jobLevel in new [] { JobLevel.Top, JobLevel.Mid, JobLevel.Low }
    from gender in new [] { Gender.Female, Gender.Male, Gender.Other }
    from color in new [] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green }
    join d in databaseData on 
        new { JobLevel = jobLevel, Gender = gender, Color = color}
        equals  new { d.JobLevel, d.Gender, d.Color } into gj
    from d in gj.DefaultIfEmpty(new { JobLevel = jobLevel, Gender = gender, Color = color, Value = 0 })
    group d by jobLevel into g
    select new EmployeeGroupValueViewModel
    {
        JobLevel = g.Key.ToString(),

        FemaleRed   = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Female && x.Color == Color.Red   ? x.Value : 0),
        FemaleBlue  = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Female && x.Color == Color.Blue  ? x.Value : 0),
        FemaleGreen = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Female && x.Color == Color.Green ? x.Value : 0),
        MaleRed     = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Male   && x.Color == Color.Red   ? x.Value : 0),
        MaleBlue    = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Male   && x.Color == Color.Blue  ? x.Value : 0),
        MaleGreen   = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Male   && x.Color == Color.Green ? x.Value : 0),
        OtherRed    = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Other  && x.Color == Color.Red   ? x.Value : 0),
        OtherBlue   = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Other  && x.Color == Color.Blue  ? x.Value : 0),
        OtherGreen  = g.Sum(x => x.Gender == Gender.Other  && x.Color == Color.Green ? x.Value : 0),
    };

var result = enrichedData.ToList();
```

You can play with this in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VsLVbJ)

Comment: typo: `Genger` => `Gender`.

Comment: I had some errors trying to achieve this but however it is also a good solution and made things clear what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @svyatoslav-danyliv Any idea why I am getting compile error with your suggested answer. It is throwing a 'The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.'

Comment: Something wrong with types in anonymous classes. Will check.

Comment: No worries, I got it working, it was caused by my entity from the db 'context.EmployeeGroupValues'. Thank you. @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: I have found bug and corrected answer.